# Extract the first row that meets a criteria in R

Tags: r

I need to extract the first time that the depth a value greater than 0.61m. I've seen several complex answers to this type of question, but I need a simple and mostly quick answer. thanks for the help

Thanks for the help.

```
rating_curve = data.frame(time_h = c(0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06),
                      depth_m = c(0, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.62))
```

Correct answer

```
[1] 0.05
```

Comment: rating_curve$time_h[which(rating_curve$depth_m>0.61)[1]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use use `>`  to create a logical vector, subset the 'time_h' using that, extract the first element (`[1]`)

```
with(rating_curve, time_h[depth_m > 0.61][1])
[1] 0.05
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237508/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-extract-the-first-row-that-meets-a-criteria-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `match` -

```
with(rating_curve, time_h[match(TRUE, depth_m > 0.61)])
#[1] 0.05
```